# mongodb 3.2 document validation disallow extra fields

Tags: mongodb, validation

we started using MongoDb and we would like to take advantage of the document validation introduced in 3.2.

We would like to disallow extra properties which are not declared in the schema. For example if the schema says :

```
"group1.a": {
  "$type": "int"
},
"group1.b": {
  "$type": "int"
}
```

I would like the following document to fail:

```
{
   "group1": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": 3
   }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to implement this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some research like [here](http://www.clusterdb.com/mongodb/document-validation-adding-just-the-right-amount-of-control-over-your-mongodb-documents) validation only check listed fields in validation schema for existence and rules. 
If field is not on the list - then it is not under validation.

As this was introduced with `3.2` then you could open a Jira ticket for this functionality [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa)

Comment: for those who are interested https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24846